# Matlab: NNTRAINTOOL requires Java which is not available

Tags: matlab

I am using Windows 7 system.
And trying to use PuTTY to connect to a linux server and run Matlab Neural Network training function on it.

Before I asked question I have looked into some similar question here. But none of them solve my problem.

The command I use to open matlab is:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop
```

And in my code I also set:

```
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
```

But I still got the error:

```
??? Error using ==> nntraintool at 28
NNTRAINTOOL requires Java which is not available

Error in ==> trainlm>train_network at 228
    [userStop,userCancel] = nntraintool('check');

Error in ==> trainlm at 113
  [net,tr] = train_network(net,tr,data,fcns,param);

Error in ==> network.train at 107
[net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);

Error in ==> generateNN at 49
    [net tr] = train(net, features, targets);

Error in ==> sixOutputNN at 30
    [ net tr ] = generateNN(features, targets, HIDDEN_LAYER, ...

Error in ==> findBestSixOutputNN at 10
        [~, tr] = sixOutputNN(features, targets, configs(i).hidden_layers, ...
```

Could anyone help me with this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to install a JVM on the host computer.  See this web site for some help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f98533.html#f122001

Answer (score 0):

Solution here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/301204

I just converted the line 33 of `nntraintool.m` from:

```
error(message('nnet:Java:NotAvailable'));
```

to

```
warning(message('nnet:Java:NotAvailable'));
```

So that I still remember that there is something fishy going on there!
It works like a charm!
This problem was present even in Matlab 2012a...